# Is there a way to give different titles to MATLAB figures being plotted inside a loop?

Tags: matlab

I am struggling to get different titles in each of my plots, below is my code and the error I keep getting:

code:

```
figure(5)
tiledlayout(2,3)
titles = ['0.1mm' '1mm' '2mm' '3mm' '4mm' '5mm'];
for i=1:length(L_PsiI1)
    Psi_array2 = L_PsiI1(i)*I_array;
    nexttile
    plot(I_array, Psi_array2)
    xlabel('Current (A)')
    ylabel('Flux (Wb)')
    grid on
    title(titles(i))
end
```

error:

`Index exceeds the number of array elements (14).`

The code works perfectly fine when I comment out the `title(titles(i))` line. I have also tried methods such as `title(['Psi-I diagram ' num2str(i)])` and `title(sprintf('Psi-I diagram %d',i))` as suggested by others. Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: The way your `titles` are defined will result in a 1x20 character array, not a 1x6 array of string. You can try `Titles={'0.1mm';'1mm';'2mm';'3mm';'4mm';'5mm'};` and then in the loop: `title(Titles{i});`

Comment: That did not seem to help but thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi Owen, welcome to SO! How is `L_PsiI1` defined? Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok will do, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the titles matrix to a cell by replacing the square brackets with curly brackets.

```
figure(5)
tiledlayout(2,3)
titles = {'0.1mm' '1mm' '2mm' '3mm' '4mm' '5mm'};
for i=1:6
    %Psi_array2 = L_PsiI1(i)*I_array;
    nexttile
    plot([1:10], [1:10])
    xlabel('Current (A)')
    ylabel('Flux (Wb)')
    grid on
    title(titles(i))
end
```